# Converting two columns into matrix form

Tags: r, matrix

I have two columns that I would like to convert into a matrix that includes binaries as its contents. For example:

If these were the columns(Name and animal):

```
Name  Animal  
Jen   Cat
Sam   Dog
Pat   Hamster
Ann   Fish
Lea   Cat
Jen   Hamster 
Sam   Hamster 
Jen   Fish
```

I would want to transform it to this format:

```
    Cat Dog Hamster Fish  
Jen  1  0   1        1
Sam  0  1   1        0
Pat  0  0   1        0
Ann  0  0   0        1
Lea  1  0   0        0
```

Comment: Maybe `table(df1$Name, df1$Animal)` ?

Comment: Oh, please don't post data as an image, previous text version was much better.

Comment: I agree on previous comment, imdages are not copy/paste friendly to play with to try to answer you later (for those willing to at all as your question lacks showing effort to solve by yourself, see [ask])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than `table` that is mentioned by @zx8754 in comments:

```
table(df$Name, df$Animal)
```

You could also use `xtabs` as follows:

```
xtabs(Col~Name+Animal, cbind(df,Col=1))

#     Animal
#Name  Cat Dog Fish Hamster
#  Ann   0   0    1       0
#  Jen   1   0    1       1
#  Lea   1   0    0       0
#  Pat   0   0    0       1
#  Sam   0   1    0       1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 
2L), .Label = c("Ann", "Jen", "Lea", "Pat", "Sam"), class = "factor"), 
    Animal = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Cat", 
    "Dog", "Fish", "Hamster"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Name", 
"Animal"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```